# What do you call a person who makes the best statements in your/a group?

Tags: single-word-requests

He says the best things, makes the smartest statements, gives the most useful information, you definitely want to listen to him when he starts talking, overall, he always says the best things and makes the best statement. In my context, it's a "he" that I'm talking about, but the word doesn't need to be gender specific.

For instance, David, who is our best sayer (?), said, "...".

So I'm thinking something like Sayer, but Sayer isn't actually a word--my criteria is usually Oxford Dictionaries. A compound word would be fine, but not a phrase.

**Edit:** To be clear, I am looking for a **noun**.

Comment: .......speaker?

Comment: *Wisest*? *Smartest*? *Educated*? *Literate*? What specific sense do you mean? Do you want a noun or an adjective?

Comment: @JasonBassford it's a translation from Arabic and the Arabic vocabulary has a comprehensive meaning. Speaker, which Edwin has suggested, might work.

Comment: @hossein None of that helps anybody who doesn't speak Arabic. You can't assume that everybody reading your question does—so put what you need into the question itself. Why something like *speaker* but not anything else that's been mentioned?

Comment: _Authority_. "We look to him as the _authority_ in our group." Or, "He is the _authority_ in our group on most important matters." Or, "He is our most _authoritative spokesperson_".

Comment: @IsabelArcher an authority is not necessarily a good speaker, and a good speaker does not necessarily have any authority.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the context, there are many words which could be used here.

*Laureate* also fits here. A **[laureate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/laureate)** is someone who has been given a very high honour because of their ability in a subject of study.

**[Intellectual](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intellectual)** is also possible.

An intellectual is a very educated person whose interests are studying and other activities that involve careful thinking and mental effort.

**[Insightful](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insightful)** can also be used.

**[Adroit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adroit)** and **[adept](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adept)** are also good words.

**Other possibilities:**

- **[Far-sighted](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/far-sighted)**.
- **[Sapient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sapient)**
- **[Well-advised](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-advised)**
- **[Sagacious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sagacious)**
- **[Shrewd](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shrewd)**

Comment: Thank you. These are all adjectives, I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: @hossein The first two words in this answer *are* nouns. Also, you don't say in your question that you're looking for a noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford I thought the implication was clear, but you are right I should have stated that clearly. The two first suggestions do not mean "speaker".

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is "spokesperson", defined by the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spokesperson) as

> a person who is chosen to speak officially for a group or organization

So you could write, "David, our spokesperson, said .."

Another alternative is "ambassador", defined by the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambassador?topic=position-and-status-in-groups-and-organizations) as

> a person who represents, speaks for, or advertises a particular organization, group of people, activity, or brand (= type of product)

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, David, who is our best sayer (?), said, "...".

For instance, David, who is our **star**, said, "...".

You do not need to use a noun that indicates that "David" speaks - the verb "to say" does that job.

**Star** has been used in this sense in English for over 1000 years:

OED

> ***Star (n.) 4. figurative and in figurative contexts.***

**a. A person or thing likened to a star, *esp. one considered as a source of inspiration or enlightenment.***

lOE   St. Giles (Corpus Cambr. 303) (1980) 106   Ðus wynsumlice gaderode se ælmihtiga God þas twegen scinende steorran [sc. the two saints] on annesse þæt hi þurhscinen eal þone eard þe hi onwunodon mid heora byrhta leoman.

1833   C. Lamb Barrenness Imaginative Faculty in Last Ess. Elia 182   Quixote—the errant Star of Knighthood, made more tender by eclipse.

This use has more or less combined with

> **c. Originally Theatre. A very famous or popular actor, singer, or other entertainer; spec. one who has top billing or takes the leading role in a film, play, etc.**

> 1808   Monthly Mirror May 405   *The star, however, of this company is Mr. Bradbury.*

And the use has broadened to encompass sport

> 2012   N. L. Macht Connie Mack viii. 149   He felt that he would never be a star and baseball had no future for him.

and general life

> **e. A person who ‘shines’ or has a brilliant reputation, esp. one who is illustrious, influential, or accomplished in a particular sphere; the most notable or outstanding person on a specified (social) occasion.**

> 1987   R. Hall Kisses of Enemy (1990) i. xvii. 104   *Sir William, bent on being the star of the occasion, took an instant loathing to the portrait in which he could see a successor to some of his own dear privileges.*

2015   Daily Nation (Kenya) (Nexis) & Mar.   *Cheating in national examinations has taken the shine off former academic stars.*